# Best Actress award announced after Best Actor award?

Tags: academy-awards

At the 2017 Academy Awards, the Best Actress award was announced after Best Actor, and before Best Picture.

Was this the first year in Oscar history that Best Actress came after Best Actor?

Do you have a source explaining how/why this decision was made?

Is there a known plan for how to order actor vs. actress awards in the future (such as alternating the order every year)?

Comment: They did seem to change things up in that one... Like announcing Best Actress and Best Picture simultaneously. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Was this the first year in Oscar history that Best Actress came after Best Actor?

No...this happened in 2012 (84th) and  2015 (87th Oscars) as well. There may be others..

> Is there a known plan for how to order actor vs. actress awards in the future (such as alternating the order every year)?

There does not seem to be a fixed schedule of alternation.but the final four are usually

- Best Director
- Best Actor / Actress (as stated no set order)
- Best Actress / Actor (as stated no set order)
- Best picture

> Do you have a source explaining how/why this decision was made?

No, and there doesn't seem to be anything on the Academy site as to the order *rules* but you must recall that the Oscar ceremony is a **production** and so the announcemen order is a part of that.

I would suggest that the order of the awards (which is announced before each show) is a part of that production so it seems likely that the order of the Best Actor/Actress is such that it will have the most *production value*.

Comment: I've deleted change to question: If you have an additional question please ask it **separately** as another question.